# ReactJs When to use contexte instead of state and when to use props instead of state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm new to React and I'm using the v17 with redux and I'm wondering about best practices.

I'm implementing a dark/light mode that affects a lot of components and I'm using the store state to save the current theme with colors to use:

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const darkMode = {
    darkMode: true,
    backgroundColor: "#1e272e",
    textColor1: "#d2dae2",
    textColor2: "#d2dae2"
};
const lightMode = {
    darkMode: false,
    backgroundColor: "#ecf0f1",
    textColor1: "#1e272e",
    textColor2: "#1e272e"
};

export const themeSlice = createSlice({
    name: "theme",
    initialState: { value: darkMode },
    reducers: {
        enableDarkMode: (state, action) => {
            state.value = darkMode;
        },
        enableLightMode: (state, action) => {
            state.value = lightMode;
        }
    }
});
export const { enableDarkMode, enableLightMode } = themeSlice.actions;
export default themeSlice.reducer;
```

I use the theme in components by calling `const theme = useSelector((state) => state.theme.value);` in the parent Component and passing it as props to the child components.

My question is it the "correct" way ? I started reading about contexte and I'm wondering if it is more appropriate to use it instead of state ? Also should I call useSelector in  parent Component and pass the values as props to the child components or should I use useSelector in every child that need to access a part of the sate ?

Thank you.

Comment: What if the parent component has nested child components, Then you would have to pass the state as prop through its child components. This is an anti-pattern. Redux is created in order to solve this pattern. So its better to call `useSelector` in child components rather than passing a global state. You can also use ContextAPI which is similar to redux

Comment: Context is good if you will use the values in different child components, across different components. While state is better if you want the values to be passed down into children. If you have 10 layers of children then its better to use context, otherwise you will have to pass down the values down through all 10 components. There is no good or bad, there is just what suits your application better.

Answer (score 0):

if you use redux  the state in the store is global so you can call it in any children or parent  so you did not obligate  to call it in the parent and pass it by props.
props: if you have a state in parent component and you need it only in a child component so pass it with props

if the state you need it in multiple component which diffuclt or impossible to pass it by props so use redux or context api or any golbal state manager